# How do you take the Taylor series of f(g(x)) in Julia?

Tags: algorithm, julia, symbolic-math, differentiation

I'm new to Julia and having problems differentiating f(g(x)) where both f(0)=0 and g(0)=0.In particular, I don't want to define f(x) or g(x) at the beginning. This would likely involve Faà di Bruno's formula and constructing set or integer partitions.

Comment: Have you considered using https://github.com/JuliaDiff/TaylorSeries.jl ?
What problems are you facing?

Comment: Yes, I've used JulliaDiff/TaylorsSeries.jl. I just need to take the Taylor series of f(g(x)). But Julia needs me to declare what f(x) is while I just need it to do a symbolic derivative.

Comment: See  See https://www.overleaf.com/read/zjwkzgftsqkm if interested. if interested.